# Standard error of product of coefficients

Tags: standard-error

Suppose that I have a regression model:
$$
y=\beta+\beta_{1}T+\beta_{2}M+\epsilon
$$
and
$$
M=\alpha+\alpha_{1}T+v
$$
In this model, $y$ is the outcome variable, $T$ is treatment, and
$M$ is the mediating variable. In the terminilogy of mediation analysis,
we have that the \textbf{causal mediation }effect is defined as $\alpha_{1}\beta_{2}$.
Using OLS on these two models, we obtain an estimate of this effect
as $\hat{\alpha}_{1}\hat{\beta}_{2}$. Although getting the point
estimate is straightforward, how would we obtain the standard error
of this effect, that is $SE\left(\hat{\alpha}_{1}\hat{\beta}_{2}\right)$?

Comment: What data did you use?  Of importance is whether you used the same responses in both procedures.

Comment: Same responses- just different models for $y$.

Comment: Please edit your post to indicate that, because it has a *huge* influence on any correct solution.  But it makes one wonder: you seem to be asking for the product of estimates of *two contradictory models.*  How do you intend to interpret that??

Comment: @whuber I Have modified the problem to more accurately suit what I have in mind.